# Receive a Custom Post Variable at notify_url with Paypal IPN

Tags: php, post, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a non-hosted button to make Paypal Payments where one of the variables is:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $payment->amount;?>">
```

This completes the Paypal payment correctly, but I'm not getting the "amount" variable back in my POST data to process using the function I've set up at my notify_url

I'm using Micah Carrick's excellent IPN listener

http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html

https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

Is it possible to modify the processIPN function to send the "amount" (or any other) variable to my function I've set up at my notify_url? I'm basically trying to ensure mc_gross is equal to the amount originally sent to be paid. I could use a database query to check mc_gross vs the expected amount but it seems inefficient if I can get the amount back as a POST variable. Just not sure if changing the IPN listener would work, and if it would, how to do it!

The process_IPN function for reference is:

```
public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

    $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    if ($post_data === null) { 
        // use raw POST data 
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->post_data = $_POST;
            $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
        } else {
            throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
        }
    } else { 
        // use provided data array
        $this->post_data = $post_data;

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
        }
    }

    if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data); 
    else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

    if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
    }

    if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
        return true;
    } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
    }
}
```

Thankyou for any help!

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while since I have worked on this but here are some code I took from my scripts.  This is the code for the Paypal buy button that I made.

```
echo '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller_38292821_biz@email.com">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Ebook">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="'.$booknumber.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.00">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value='.$custom.'>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="'.$quantity.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/ipn.php">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/support.php?clearcart=1">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/ipncancel.php?status=cancel">';
echo '<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="paypal.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">';
echo '</form>';
```

I had a field called "custom" that I use to pass on whatever data I need to do validation.  I used that field to pass the username of the customer that made a purchase and when my listener script (ipn.php) received the POST, it takes the username and queries the database and checks the amount of the transaction against the amount from the POST and if they match, I run another query to update the database to make the digital product available to the account with that username.  Here is the condition that must be satisfied before the digital product is made available to the user's account.

```
    if($quantity == $pendingquantity && $payment_amount == $pendingamount && $payment_currency == "USD" && $payment_status == "Completed"){

    //Update database to make the product available for download for the specified account.

    }
```

Hopefully, this might give you an idea of how to go about setting things up.